# Build on the Build Server Error: CS1730, After updating the Projects

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

Step 1:
Do the edit for following to the *.*proj files

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.-->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Version VersionFile="..\VersionInfo.txt" RevisionType="Increment">
      <Output TaskParameter="Major" PropertyName="Major" />
      <Output TaskParameter="Minor" PropertyName="Minor" />
      <Output TaskParameter="Build" PropertyName="Build" />
      <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
    </Version>
    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS" OutputFile=".\Properties\AssemblyVersion.cs" AssemblyVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" AssemblyFileVersion="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)" />
  </Target>
  <!--
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
```

Step 2:
Remove the AssemblyVersion number, and AssemblyFileVersion from the AssemblyInfo.cs

Step 3:
Create a file called VersionInfo.text outside where the sln resides.

Step 3:
Include the AssemblyVersionNumber.cs into the project's

Step 4:
Issue a MSBuild, Works fine on local machine, but not on the build server.

DevMachine: (32 bit)

```
C:\SVNHome\branches\MyGreatProject-II>msbuild -ver
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.3643]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.
```

BuildServer:

```
D:\SVNHome\branches\source\MyGreatProject-II>%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\msbuild
 -ver
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.4234]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.
```

Error Message given on the build server is not helping.

> Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs: error CS1730: Assembly and module
>   attributes must precede all other elements defined in a file except
>   using clauses and extern alias declarations

Comment: So what does the `AssemblyVersion.cs` look like on both systems?

Comment: Question, I have a small problem now. all the projects give me different increment numbers all my binaries are not the same.

Comment: Which build server technology are you using. You should be calling the Increment only once for a build. So you probably need to include that in an earlier place than the call that builds all the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Its my bad, Went on to the Server,

1. Undo all checkouts on the build Server
2. Force a build, then it worked fine.
3. Thank you Jessehouwing. That was it.